# How to use the classifier obtained by Pyml

Tags: python, dataset, svm, libsvm, pyml

I am a new user of PyML in Python. Using [the tutorial](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html), I did the following:

```
from PyML import *
data = SparseDataSet("heart")
s = SVM()
s.train(data) 
r = s.cv(data,5)
```

I got the resultset `r`, but I don't understand how to use this resultset to classify a totally new instance with Python. Can anyone more experienced help me? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `r = s.sv(data,5)` you are doing crossvalidation, which is used to measure classifier performance by training and testing 5 times on different parts of the dataset. This is not necessary when your objective is to classify new instances.

To classify new instances, you should preferably have these in a different dataset and use the test method of the SVM object after training:

```
s = SVM()
s.train(trainingDataset)
r = s.test(testDataset)
```

You will then have the results from classifying new instances in testDataset.
An option to using `s.test()` is to use `s.classify(data, i)` and `s.decisionFunc(data, i)` for classifying individual data points after training, but this is not recommended in the tutorial documentation as you will not get the extra result information contained in a result object (like you get from `s.test`, `s.cv` or `s.stratifiedCV` methods).

Comment: If you want to check what class each datapoint was predicted to be you need to use the r.getPredictedLabels()

Comment: Sorry to revisit this, but it doesn't seem to me that s.test can be used for classifying new instances. Also, what is the argument i in s.classify, s.decisionFunc?